# How to forward to browser's home (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

```
function goHome()  { 

  if (window.home) { // NS
    window.home();
  }
  else { // IE and Google Chrome
    if (navigator.appVersion.split("MSIE")[1] <= 7) { // IE 4-7
      window.location = "about:home";
    }
    else if (window.location.href) { // Google Chrome
      window.location.href = "??????????";            // <<-- what is the built-in 
    }                                                 //      link for the home button
    else { // IE 8, 9
      // ...
    }
  }

}
```

However, I do not know the built-in link for the home button in Google Chrome. Does anybody has an idea?

PS. The JavaScript code is incomplete and just a snippet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, the home page is either an actual URL, or the New Tab page.

So, it *would* be `chrome://newtab/`, except that if you [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/LVP5J/) on a page, you'll raise this security error:

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   chrome://newtab/

(see the error in Chrome's Developer Tools)

So, I don't think it's possible. I could be wrong, I'm no expert on Chrome.

`chrome://newtab/` does take you to the right place if you paste it into your address bar, but that is obviously useless to you.